# https://www routing not working in route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53

I have set up routing in aws route53 for my domain (lets call it example.com) for both www.example.com and example.com. I have created a RecordSet for each in Route53. They both point to Alias target of LoadBalancer. There is SSL certificate attached to LB.

`http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` routings are working fine. `https://example.com`  routing works fine but `https://www.example.com` is not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your SSL certificate support the `www.` subdomain as an alternative name?

Comment: What error do you get for this routing www.example.com?

Comment: SSL certificate supports www. I have recreated Hosted Zone and Record sets and it works fine now. I suspect I made some mistake configuring Record Sets first time. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I'm struggling with this exact issue. Can you provide some more information on what you think solved your problem?

Comment: Solved my problem by Route53 > Hosted zones > mydomain.com > Create Record Set > Name: www.mydomain.com, Type: A, Alias: mydomain.com